# How to open a connection from mysql.connector.pooling with a "with" in python?

Tags: python, mysql

im having mysql connections in mysqlpool (mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool)

i want to get a connection from pool , 
using "with" 
 like :
      with connect(**conn_info) as conn:
         cur = conn.cursor()
im not able to do that , it fails while opening a connection using with.

is there a way to do so ?

(use this code to reproduce it)

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector.connection import MySQLConnection
from mysql.connector import pooling
# try:

connection_pool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name="pynative_pool",pool_size=2, pool_reset_session=True, host='192.168.50.91', database='sample', user='usr', password='abc')

print ("Printing connection pool properties ")
print("Connection Pool Name - ", connection_pool.pool_name)
print("Connection Pool Size - ", connection_pool.pool_size)
# Get connection object from a pool


def abc(connection_object):     
    # if connection_object.is_connected():
    db_Info = connection_object.get_server_info()
    print("Connected to MySQL database using connection pool ... MySQL Server version on ",db_Info)
    # i want to open this connection using a with
    cursor = connection_object.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from nmi_lambda limit 10")
    record = cursor.fetchone()
    # c.close()
    print ("Your connected to - ", record)
    return record

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    # unable to do this "with connect(**conn_info) as conn"
    connection_object = connection_pool.get_connection()
    record =  abc(connection_object)
    # connection_object.close()
    return record


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: how does it fail exactly ?

Comment: Exception is:     __enter__      this is what i get , with expects this and i guess its not there

Comment: (undescore_underscore_enter_undescore_underscore) _ is getting ommited here in comments   __enter__

Comment: Could you please add the code to reproduce it in your post, and the error message ?

Comment: kindly check i have added the same code

Comment: Please try to minimize the code to something we can reproduce. It may help you to spot the error too.